# How do I get Helenus to return the actual value of a CQL query?

Tags: node.js, cassandra, cql, helenus

I am using Node.js with Helenus to connect to a Cassandra DB.

I have a query:
SELECT score FROM team_scores WHERE team_name = 'foo'

When run from cqlsh, I get results that look like this:

```
score
-------
10
```

I then move the query over to Node and Helenus using cqlVersion 3.0.0. When I run this code:

```
pool.cql("SELECT score FROM team_scores WHERE team_name = 'foo'", function(err, results){
    console.log(results);
  });
```

The console reports:

```
[ <Row: Key: 'foo', ColumnCount: 1, Columns: [ 'score' ]> ]
```

What am I missing to get Helenus to return me the actual value of score rather than whatever it seems to be returning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

results is actually a list of row objects.  You are probably seeing the result of a toString implementation.

Here is some good code to log out the results of a select:

```
results.forEach(function(row){
  //all row of result
  row.forEach(function(name,value,ts,ttl){
    //all column of row
    console.log(name,value,ts,ttl);
  });

});
```

you can read more at the [helenus github](https://github.com/simplereach/helenus).  See the stuff on the bottom about the row object.

Answer (score 2):

```
results.forEach(function(row){
  var score = row.get('score').value;
  console.log(score); //will give you 10
});
```